# C# split by regex

Tags: c#, regex

I have a little problem that I don't know how to call it like, so I will do my best to explain you that.

```
String text = "Random text over here boyz, I dunno what to do";
```

I want to take by split only `over here boyz` for example, I want to let split the word `text` and the word `,` and it will show me the whole text that in thoose 2 strings. Any ideas?

Thank you,
Sagi.

Comment: there is a `String.Split` method https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.split(v=vs.110).aspx  ?

Comment: So, basically, you want  "`over here boyz`" returned by splitting the string?

Comment: The first question one needs to ask themself when wanting to split a string is: "What text am I looking for and how can I identify it?". If this is described by, for example, "the third to fifth word in a sentence, including attached punctuation", you can start writing a regex.

Comment: @Pogrindis - I didn't found the answer right there.

Comment: @Sam - That's right.

Comment: @CodeCaster - But it isn't fixed text, it is changing the whole time, I'm just need the same text.

Comment: I'm simply need a .Split that gets 2 strings and return what there is between thoose 2 strings.

Comment: Then make it `return "over here boyz,";`? It's really unclear what text specifically you're looking for. Show a couple of example input and outputs.

Comment: Can you provide more information on the source of these string is?

Comment: Inputs:
I love cakes id="sdfsadf" the best cake
Cakes like id="asdfasf" are da best
I love stackoverflow and id="ifgndignidfgnfdgdfg" the amazing ppl over there

Outputs:
sdfsadf
asdfasf
ifgndignidfgnfdgdfg

Comment: @CodeCaster - I did.

Comment: Now suddenly you want to obtain `id="{this text}"` from a string, which is entirely different from the example in your question and for which you don't need splitting. Please update your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your comments I get that from this string:

```
foo bar id="baz" qux
```

You want to obtain the value `baz`, because it is in the `id="{text}"` pattern.

For that you can use a regular expression:

```
string result = Regex.Match(text, "id=\"(.*?)\"").Groups[1].Value;
```

Note that this will match any character. Also note that this will yield false positives, like `fooid="bar"`, and that this won't match unquoted values.

So all in all, for parsing HTML, you should not use regular expressions. Try HtmlAgilityPack and an XPath expression.

Comment: That's almost the right answer, one problem:

My string is like that:
foo bar id="baz" asdfsadfsdaf=""

So the output is like 
baz " asdasdasd=

Comment: Yeah that's nice. Like I said, include all examples in a readable form in your question.

Comment: Yes I'm sry, but as I said in my original code that isn't working cause of that. There is anything I will be able to do?

Comment: I made the regex nongreedy. Again, [**update your question**](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/33186859/edit).

Comment: Never mind, its working cause of something I did, thanks man (:

Answer (score 0):

There is a Split overload that can receive multiple string seperators:

```
var rrr = text.Split(new string[] { ",", "text" }, StringSplitOptions.None);
```

If you would like to extract only the text between these two strings using regex you can do something like this:

```
var pattern = @"text(.*),";
var a = new Regex(pattern).Match(text);
var result = a.Groups[1];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Regex class:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/library/ze12yx1d%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

But first of all (as it was said) you need to clarify for yourself how you will identify string that you want.

Answer (score 0):

in first case you can use

```
string stringResult;
if (text.Contains("over here boyz"))
    stringResult = string.Empty;
else
    stringResult = "over here boyz";
```

but the second case can solve by this code

```
String text = "Random text over here boyz, I dunno what to do";           
//Second dream without whitespace
var result = Regex.Split(text, " *text *| *, *");
foreach (var x in result)
{
    Console.WriteLine(x);
}

//Second dream with whitespace
result = Regex.Split(text, "text|,");
foreach (var x in result)
{
    Console.WriteLine(x);
}
```

You can train to write Regex with this tool http://www.regexbuddy.com/ or http://www.regexr.com/